# Passing a 256-bit wire to a C function through the Verilog VPI

Tags: c, verilog

I have a 256-bit value in Verilog:

```
reg [255:0] val;
```

I want to define a system task $foo that calls out to external C using the VPI, so I can call $foo like this:

```
$foo(val);
```

Now, in the C definition for the function 'foo', I cannot simply read the argument as an integer (PLI_INT32), because I have too many bits to fit in one of those.  But, I can read the argument as a string, which is the same thing as an array of bytes.  Here is what I wrote:

```
static int foo(char *userdata) {
  vpiHandle systfref, args_iter, argh;
  struct t_vpi_value argval;
  PLI_BYTE8 *value;

  systfref = vpi_handle(vpiSysTfCall, NULL);
  args_iter = vpi_iterate(vpiArgument, systfref);

  argval.format = vpiStringVal;
  argh = vpi_scan(args_iter);
  vpi_get_value(argh, &argval);
  value = argval.value.str;

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    vpi_printf("%.2x ", value[i]);
  }
  vpi_printf("\n");

  vpi_free_object(args_iter);
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this code reads the argument as a string and then prints out each character (aka byte) in the string.  This works *almost* perfectly.  However, the byte `00` always gets read as `20`.  For example, if I assign the Verilog reg as follows:

```
 val = 256'h000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f;
```

And call it using `$foo(val)`, then the C function prints this at simulation time:

```
VPI: 20 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f
```

I have tested this with many different values and have found that the byte `00` always gets mapped to `20`, no matter where or how many times it appears in `val`.

Also, note that if I read the value in as a `vpiHexStrVal`, and print the string, it looks fine.

So, two questions:

1. Is there a better way to read in my 256-bit value from the Verilog?
2. What's going on with the `20`?  Is this a bug?  Am I missing something?

Note: I am using Aldec for simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vpiStringVal` is used when the value is expected to be ASCII text, in order to get the value as a pointer to a C string.  This is useful if you want to use it with C functions that expect a C string, such as `printf()` with the `%s` format, `fopen()`, etc.  However, C strings cannot contain the null character (since null is used to terminate C strings), and also cannot represent x or z bits, so this is not a format that should be used if you need to distinguish any possible vector value.  It looks like the simulator you are using formats the null character as a space (0x20); other simulators just skip them, but that doesn't help you either.  To distinguish any possible vector value use either `vpiVectorVal` (the most compact representation) or `vpiBinStrVal` (a binary string with one 0/1/x/z character for each bit).

Comment: I didn't want to use `vpiBinStrVal` or `vpiVectorVal`, because it was inconvenient to have the input formatted one bit at a time.  I actually want the data to formatted as 32 8-bit values; I ended up just splicing the 256-bit wire and sending it in as 8 32-bit inputs, which can be read as `vpiIntVal`, and trivially converting that to an array of 32 bytes.

Comment: Ok but `vpiVectorVal` allows you to read the bits as 32-bit words; it is not one bit at a time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and I misspoke.  What I mean is I want an actual integral value, not something that has 'x' and 'z' in it.  Not a big deal though, I can convert it.

Comment: If you don't care about x and z you can just read only the `aval` fields and ignore `bval`.